# Get the original query object in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a loop to perform multiple queries through Mongoose

```
"use strict";

var Mongoose = require("mongoose");
var User     = Mongoose.model("User");
var Cache    = {};

for (var index=0; index<usernames.length; index++) {
    var query = {
        username:usernames[index]
    };

    User.find(query).
    exec(function(error,users){
        //THIS IS A CALLBACK FUNCTION,
        //HOW TO GET THE 'query' VARIABLE ABOVE?
        //I WANT TO PUT THE RESULT INTO CACHE:
        var username    = users[0].username;
        Cache[username] = users[0];
    });
}
```

**I need to know which result is of which query, in the callback function above.
It is for db query caching purpose.** I can extract 'username' from 'users[0]', but when the array 'users' is empty, there's no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put anonymous function inside your loop; and use `.findOne()` instead of `.find()` if you are only interested in the first user or if the `username` values are unique.

```
  for (var index = 0; index < usernames.length; index++) {
    (function () {
        var query = {
            username: usernames[index]
        };

        User.findOne(query).
            exec(function (error, user) {
                //use your query here
                var username = user.username;
                Cache[username] = user;
            });
    })()
}
```

However consider [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this kind of operations.